# L20n complex plurals

Tags: javascript, localization, l20n

According to the [l20n](/questions/tagged/l20n) [documentation example](http://l20n.org/learn/putting-it-all-together-complex-plurals-example/), the library can support "*complex language plurals*".

> In the Firefox download panel, a string like this shows up while
>   downloading file:
>
> `4 hours, 1 minute and 26 seconds remaining`.

Unfortunately, the given example seems not work with the [`3.0.4`](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/releases/tag/v3.0.4) release.

HTML markup:

```
<span data-l10n-id="minutesAgo" data-l10n-args="{'minutes':52}">⁨</span>
```

Language file (`en-US.l20n`):

```
# Date time
<pluralDateTime($n) {
  $n == 0 ? "zero" :
  $n % 100 == 1 ? "one" :
  $n % 100 == 2 ? "two" :
  $n % 100 == 3 || $n % 100 == 4 ? "few" :
  "many"
}>
<_minutes {
  one: "minute",
  two: "minutes",
  few: "minutes",
  many: "minutes"
}>

<minutesAgo "{{ $minutes }} {{ _minutes[pluralDateTime($minutes)] }} ago">
```

Current Result:

```
52 undefined ago
```

Expected result:

```
52 minutes ago
```

What is the **current syntax** for plurals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom plural macros are only currently available on the v1.x branch.  In 3.x we reduced the scope of the syntax support and focused on the integration with HTML and the webstack.

In 3.x, you can use the built-in plural macros which are available under the `@cldr.plural` global.  Check [the en-US file in the examples/ folder](https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/c689f5d21da6f299cbaaf6a3b1fea79e8070c440/examples/locales/example.en-US.l20n#L6) to see what the usage looks like, or my fork of the L20n Tinker using the v3.x branch: http://stasm.github.io/tinker/.

We have a todo item to document the current scope of the syntax support on v3.x.  I'll update this answer once it has been done.